# Google map API2 addListener

Tags: google-maps-api-2

i have store all the markers in a makers array, and when i click on the marker i would like to retrieve the index from the array. however this doesn't return me with the correct index, instead it return the max index. Any suggestion?

```
for(var i = 0; i<options.length; i++){
marker[i] = new GMarker(new GLatLng(options[i].latitude, options[i].longitude), markerIcon);
//addListener(i, options[i].name);
GEvent.addListener(marker[i],"click", function(e) {
alert(i);
});
map.addOverlay(marker[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the variable `i` is not being captured in a closure, like you would expect. So, all listeners are capturing the same `i` (which is eventually incremented to options.length). You need to wrap the marker/listener creation in its own function.

```
var makeNewMarker = function(i) {
  var marker = new GMarker(
      new GLatLng(options[i].latitude, options[i].longitude),
      markerIcon);
  GEvent.addListener(marker[i],"click", function(e) {
    alert(i);
  });
};
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; ++i) {
  marker[i] = makeNewMarker(i);
  map.addOverlay(marker[i]);
}
```

You could make the `makeNewMarker` function an anonymous function inside the for-loop, but this way seems more readable.